# None of these students speaks/speak

Tags: grammar

Is my understanding correct that I can use "none of them" with a plural verb when meaning "not any of them", for example, "none of these students speak English". But if I mean "not one of them" then I use the singular verb "none of these students speaks English." If I use "you" or "them" the verb should be plural: "none of them speak English". "None of them/you  speaks" is wrong  because like "none of you", "none of them"  can only be a group of people not a single person. Am I right?

Comment: I am confused  according to this article either none of them is or are is correct. https://editorsmanual.com/articles/none-is-or-are/

Comment: No: none" simply entails "not one" / "not any". It occurs freely with either singular or plural agreement.

Comment: Listen up @Antonia A. "None of them" entails "not one of them" which means the same as "not any of them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To negate a reference for individual people or things, use a singular verb; for an entire group, use a plural verb.

Although some pedants insist that 'none of' only means 'not one of' and therefore must be followed by a singular verb, modern English usage allows 'none of' to mean 'not any of' and so to be followed by a plural verb.

> This rumor [*that none of' means only 'not one of'*] is more than 200
> years old, and it's based on the fact that the word none is from an
> old English word that means not one. That part is true. But, unlike
> our modern English phrase, not one, that old English word could be
> either singular or plural.
>
> The fact is that none has been used with
> plural verbs for more than a thousand years. Not only that, but none,
> in modern English, doesn't mean only not one. It also means not any,
> as in, half a doughnut is better than none. And it means no part, or
> nothing, as in, I want to hear none of this foolishness about a lack
> of doughnuts.
>
> **Usage experts acknowledge that none is sometimes
> singular and sometimes plural. They mostly recommend that you treat it
> as singular when it means not one, or no amount, and plural when it
> means not any.**

[Is 'none' singular or plural? (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/video/is-none-singular-or-plural#:%7E:text=Usage%20experts%20acknowledge%20that%20none,get%20you%20doughnuts%2C%20or%20coffee.)

Comment: so only "none of you" is exception and takes only the plural verb because it refers to many people. Right? But "none of us" and "none of them" "none of these students or people" can all take either a singular or the plural verb. Right? None of them/us/these people/students is/are/work/works.

Comment: @AntoniaA "None" simply entails "not one" / "not any". It occurs freely with either singular or plural agreement.

Comment: @BillJ Then why did a native speaker correct me and say that "none of you are" is correct while "none of you is" is wrong. None of them speaks  is wrong. None of these students speak is also wrong. I don't understand. Yes, I follow the rule you mention, but some native speakers think what I wrote is wrong.

Comment: @AntoniaA - if you are faced with the choice between (1) what a 'native speaker' says without any support and (2) what an authority such as a dictionary says, you will be wise to choose the second of these.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you are right. Thus all of the following is correct: None of these students speak or speaks. None of us/them/you is/are invited. Depending whether I am talking about " not one of them" or "not any of them". Right?

Comment: @AntoniaA No: "not one of them" entails "not any of them".

Comment: @BillJ, I understand that but your explanation seems to be different from this one :
With countable nouns, where you mean not a single one out of a number of individual things or people (answering how many?):
None [of them] is / Not [even] *one* of them is​
None [of them] are / Not *any* of them are = All of them are not

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/none-of-singular-plural-verb.3638989/. It's post 11

Comment: @BillJ And I am trying to understand that taking into account different opinions I can say that all the the following examples are correct, aren't they?  With either a singular or a plural verb: None of these students speak or speaks. None of us/them/you is/are invited. Are they correct?